# Related rates with respect to time

Tags: calculus

The sun is shining and a spherical snowball of volume 340  ft$^3$  is melting at a rate of 10 cubic feet per hour. As it melts, it remains spherical. At what rate is the radius changing after 2.5 hours?

Please help I'm really confused
340-10*2.5 = 315
so
(-10) = 4pi/3 * ?

Comment: please help I'm still stuck with stupid answers

Answer (score 0):

First, you must know what it is you need to solve for. When it asks for the rate at which the radius is changing after 2.5 hours, it means the change in r with respect to t, or $\frac{dr}{dt}$.

Since the snowball is a sphere, we know

$V = \frac43 \pi r^3$

Then we can derive on both sides as follows

$\frac{dV}{dt} = 4 \pi r^2 \frac{dr}{dt}$

Now, we have already been given that the change in volume with respect to time is

$\frac{dV}{dt} = -10$

and we can calculate that after 2.5 hours, our snowball will have a volume of

$340 - 10(2.5) = 315$.

So

$315 = \frac43 \pi r^3$

and we can find that

$r = 4.221$

From here, we can simply plug into our previous equation as follows

$-10 = 4 \pi (4.221)^2 \frac{dr}{dt}$

$\frac{-10}{4 \pi (4.221)^2} = \frac{dr}{dt}$

$-0.0447 = \frac{dr}{dt}$

Therefore our radius is decreasing at a rate of 0.0447 feet per hour after 2.5 hours.